# Summing Columns of a List of Dictionaries (from CSV) in python

Tags: python

I uploaded a CSV to python using DictReader:

```
import unicodecsv

with open('lahman-csv_2015-01-24/batting.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(f)
    batting = list(reader)

batting[0]

{u'2B': u'0',
 u'3B': u'0',
 u'AB': u'4',
 u'BB': u'0',
 u'CS': u'0',
 u'G': u'1',
 u'GIDP': u'',
 u'H': u'0',
 u'HBP': u'',
 u'HR': u'0',
 u'IBB': u'',
 u'R': u'0',
 u'RBI': u'0',
 u'SB': u'0',
 u'SF': u'',
 u'SH': u'',
 u'SO': u'0',
 u'lgID': u'NA',
 u'playerID': u'abercda01',
 u'stint': u'1',
 u'teamID': u'TRO',
 u'yearID': u'1871'}
```

I have written this function to sum certain columns based on key:

```
def sum_columns(key_list, dictionary_list):
    for key in key_list:
        for i in range(0,len(dictionary_list)):
            sum_one = sum(dictionary_list[i][key])
        print sum_one  

key_list = ['RBI', 'R']
sum_columns(key_list, batting)
```

When running this, I get this error:

```
<ipython-input-45-3b0d2b3348b8> in sum_columns(key_list, dictionary_list)
      4     for key in key_list:
      5         for i in range(0,len(dictionary_list)):
----> 6             sum_one = sum(dictionary_list[i][key])
      7         print sum_one
      8 

KeyError: 'RBI'
```

Comment: Aside: Why not use `for i in dictionary_list:` and then use `i[key]` (instead of getting in `range`)?

Comment: Can you answer with an example using this?

Comment: I am unable to repro your error. I am getting a `TypeError` which is expected as you have used `sum` on a unicode literal. Look up the docs for `sum`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum

Comment: I would do something like `sum_one = sum(map(int,[j[i] for i in key_list for j in dictionary_list]))`.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, KeyError: 'RBI'

Comment: Sorry, I can't go further with this. It is working perfectly fine https://ideone.com/ISQazJ. Hopefully someone else might help you.

Comment: The answer of @BhargavRao is good. If you keep the same syntax that you  had originally the `key Error` is due that `dictionary_list[i][key]` is actually `dictionary_list[1]['RBI']` and because that your dictionnary is `1` not 2  so it should be `dictionary_list[0]['RBI']`

Answer (score 1):

you should elaborate your syntax or use `pudb your_script.py` to have more clue about your error.

the key Error is due that `dictionary_list[i][key]` is actually `dictionary_list[1]['RBI']` and because that your dictionnary size is `1` not `2` (i.e `[0,1]`) so it should be `dictionary_list[0]['RBI']`

```
batting = [{u'2B': u'0', u'BB': u'0', u'HR': u'0',
 u'IBB': u'', u'3B': u'0', u'stint': u'1', u'GIDP': u'',
  u'playerID': u'abercda01', u'HBP': u'', u'teamID': u'TRO',
   u'AB': u'4', u'G': u'1', u'H': u'0', u'yearID': u'1871',
    u'R': u'0', u'RBI': u'0', u'CS': u'0', u'lgID': u'NA',
     u'SH': u'', u'SO': u'0', u'SB': u'0', u'SF': u''}]


def sum_columns(key_list, dictionary_list):
  sum_one = []
  for key in key_list:
      size_dictionary =len(dictionary_list)#1
      for i in range(0,size_dictionary):#for i in [0]
          value = dictionary_list[i][key]
          sum_one.append(sum(map(int,value)))
      print sum_one


key_list = ['RBI', 'R']
sum_columns(key_list, batting) 

'''
[0]
[0, 0]
'''
```

The only thing that I don't understand with your question is what happen if you change your `key_list` to `['teamID', 'R']` because the key `teamID` refers to `u'TRO'` so I don't understand why or how you would want a sum of this?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in "RBI" for a column name, but in the dictionary the key is **u**"RBI".

You can make the intent of the function a bit clearer using a generator expression:

```
def sum_columns(key_list, dictionary_list):
    for key in key_list:
        column = (dictionary[key] for dictionary in dictionary_list)
        print sum(column)
```

If you are using python 2.7.11 or newer, this will return a dictionary of the summed columns indexed by key:

```
def sum_columns(keys, dictionaries):
    return {k:sum(d[k] for d in dictionaries) for k in keys}
```